# SCRIPT5007: The value of the property onclick="JavaScript:functionName('name', '2', '0') is null or undefined, not a Function object(ie8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

[IE8 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucNa9.png)

SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'webTabFunction' is null or undefined, not a Function object(ie8)
Error coming in ie8 rest all browser working fine.

```
<a href="#debit_card_info" onclick="JavaScript:webTabFunction('debit_card_info', '2', '0')">Debit Card</a>
```

Function:-

```
function webTabFunction(e,a,t){ }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` should be:  `onclick="webTabFunction('debit_card_info', '2', '0')"`